# JQuery serialize doesn't work on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

I'm using the jQuery .serialize function and can't get it to serialize the this particular dyamic elements form on submit. Note that I've tried the form on static and dynamic code and it worked fine. But I can't find the bug in this code

Here's my form code

```
<%= form_tag({action: :show}, method: "post", id: "ajax-show") do %>
            <select id="xtime">
              <% (0..95).each do |min| %>
                  <option><%= Time.at(min*15*60).utc.strftime("%H:%M") %></option>
              <% end %>
            </select>
            <input id="xprice" value="12"/>
            <a href="#" id="price-add">add</a>

            <ul id="price-list">

            </ul>
            <hr/>
            <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
        <% end %>
```

and here's my jQuery code

```
    $("form#ajax-show").on('submit', function (e) {
        'use strict';
        e.preventDefault();
        console.debug($(this).serializeJSON());
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#price-add', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var t = '<input enabled checked type="checkbox" name="times[]" value="' + $('#xtime').val() + '"/>' + $('#xtime').val();
        var p = '<input enabled checked type="checkbox" name="prices[]" value="' + $('#xprice').val() + '"/>' + $('#xprice').val();
        $('#price-list').append('<li>time:  ' + t + '  .  price: ' + p + '  .  <a href="#" id="price-remove">remove</a></li>')
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#price-remove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
    });
```

Comment: select tag needs a name attr

Comment: Already tried that, but I don't want to show the submit the select tag, I want to submit the <li> tag that's put dynamically

Comment: Are you searching this: `JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray())`?

Comment: I cant get what you want.

Comment: I have dropdown menu that I choose values from, those values are then added to the form in <li> tag inside the <ul> specified. I can't get those in serialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should help you:

```
$("form#ajax-show").on('submit', function (e) {
  'use strict';
  e.preventDefault();
  var formEmulation = $("<form/>").append($("#price-list"));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formEmulation.serializeArray()));
});
```